# USB Microphone is creating a beeping noise

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, microphone, headset

I recently bought another headset, as my other ones were creating a lot of static noise. I used to have 3 headsets which worked fine in the past, but cause a lot of static noise now, they were all direct line headphones, and my friend suggested I get a USB microphone. He tested his USB headset on my PC and there was no beeping.

But I just bought a new headset, tried it on my PC, and it has a very loud annoying beeping noise, constantly when I speak, everyone on teamspeak can hear it, and I can hear when recording. However, when I plug the same headset into my laptop, it has no beeping noise, but has background noise instead.

I have tried plugging it into all 6 USB ports on my PC, but none of them solve the problem. I've tried editing some settings within the recording device options, but nothing works.

I do not know the name of the headset itself, however, here is the link to headset I bought off Ebay:  http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-2-0-Stereo-Headset-Headphone-w-Mic-Laptop-Computer-PC-MSN-SKYPE-Games-VoIP-/140824992042?pt=UK_Headsets&hash=item20c9d2d92a

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: You might be referring to [audio feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_feedback).

Answer (score 1):

- Go to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Speech Recognition`
- Choose `Set up microphone`
- Choose the type of your microphone
- Try to make as loud noise as possible

So your microphone noise will be reduced

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problems with this headset.

I have found that the beeping isn't as loud when you set the format to 44100Hz but does change to an even more annoying irregular beep/screech. Other than that I have not found a complete fix. I'm fairly sure it has nothing to do with feedback just the quality of the mic itself. I suggest to simply get a new, better quality headset.

- Edit -

If you have specific KB_MS_USB ports, plug the Headset into one of those and set it to 48000 Hz. So far, no more beeping. Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I bought a AUX extender cable and pluged in into that. I also lowered the frequency to 44100Hz. This has worked for now.